# Google Mock without using the mocked object directly (C++)

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am new to Google Mock. I have a class `A`, that is using class `B`. I want to write a test that will test `A`, without running `B`, as `B` uses the outside world.

My question: How can I invoke a test on `A`, and have it use the Mocked instance of `B`?

E.g.

```
A a;
Mock_B mock_b;
EXPECT_CALL(mock_b, foo(4));

//test call of a
EXPECT_EQ(0, a.bar());
```

When I do this, `a` uses `B` rather than `Mock_B`.

Comment: You cannot. Class `A` needs to use an interface, that is mocked with `Mock_B`, instead of a `B` instance directly.

Answer (score 0):

> *"How can I invoke a test on A, and have it use the Mocked instance of B?"*

You cannot, unless you change class `A` to use an interface of `B`, instead of using a `class B` instance directly.

It's pretty well explained in more depth here: [Google Mock's Beginner Introduction](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies).